# Best way to find the Coordinates of a Point on a Line-Segment a specified Distance Away from another Point

Tags: math, optimization, computational-geometry

Image of the problem at:

[image]

In my code I have 4 points: `Q`, `R` ,`S` , `T`.

I know the following

- Coordinates for `R`, `T`, and `S`;
- That segment `RT < RQ < RS`;
- I need to figure out the coordinates of `Q`.

I already know point `Q` can be found on the line segment `TS`. However I need to get the coordinates for `Q` and `I` need it to be a relatively efficient calculation.

I have several solutions for this problem but they are all so convoluted and long I know I must be doing something wrong. I feel certain there must a simple elegant way to solve this. The best solution would be one that minimizes the number of more intensive calculations but that also isn't ridiculously long.

Comment: Ask on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: as Manoj said - this does not belong here - but If you choose to post this into math.stackexchange.com a short hint from my side: write what you allready did! If you want us to solve your homework you can tell us at least what you've tried so far.

Comment: Perhaps you should post your solution and ask if it can be shortened. Your question is now of-topic on SO, IMO.

Comment: Are you sure your list of what is known is complete? I don't see how the coordinates of Q can be reduced below a range of possibilities with only those two facts.

Comment: The list of what is known is missing a crucial fact from the title: d is also given. Since it is strictly between RT and RS, the solution is unique.

Comment: I'm not so sure that would be the place for it. The computational overhead of the solution is fairly important to the solution. I'm not looking for an answer, I'm looking for an efficient answer.

Comment: I solved the formula for angle x for both triangles then set them equal to each other. When i tried to solve for E I got the following (the letters used for the coordinates are slightly different here): EDIT Posting the whole link to it failed but the is answer is a bit ridiculous considering its not the final solution.

Comment: ((a^2+c^2-b^2)/c = X = (n^2+a^2-d^2)/n then I solved for n.

Comment: Actually a good approximation would be fine if it cut down on the overhead significantly. Would a function that found the midpoint, compared versus length D then repeated for a series of iterations be faster then the perfect solutions?

Comment: @David: I put an iterative approximation into my answer below.

Comment: Why is this closed? A mathematicians approach is not what i'm looking for. I'm looking for a method that's fastest in code, not a method for calculating by hand, and I dont need 100% precision.

Comment: @David, I guess it's closed because you haven't posted any code. If you'd posted your own solution (like I recommended) and had asked how that solution could be improved, it might not have been closed.

Answer (score 1):

Q is the intersecting point between a circle of radius d around R and the line TS, which leads to a quadratic equation with a number of parameters in the coefficients. I don't know if the following if “the best” solution (it may even be better to use a numerical solver in between), but it is completely worked out. Because I think it's more readable, I've changed your coordinate names to put T at (T1, T2), S at (S1, S2) and, to keep the formulas shorter, R at (0, 0) – just adjust S and T  and the returned values accordingly.

```
tmp1 = S1^2 - S2*T2 - S1*T1 + S2^2;
tmp2 = sqrt(- S1^2*T2^2 + S1^2*d^2 + 2*S1*S2*T1*T2 - 2*S1*T1*d^2 -
      S2^2*T1^2 + S2^2*d^2 - 2*S2*T2*d^2 + T1^2*d^2 + T2^2*d^2);
tmp3 = S1^2 - 2*S1*T1 + S2^2 - 2*S2*T2 + T1^1 + T2^2;
t = (tmp1 + tmp2)/tmp3;
if (0 > t || t > 1) {
  // pick the other solution instead
  t = (tmp1 - tmp2)/tmp3;
}
Q1 = S1+t*(T1-S1);
Q2 = S2+t*(T2-S2);
```

Obviously, I take no warranties that I made no typos etc. :-)

EDIT: Alternatively, you could also get a good approximation by some iterative method (say, Newton) to find a zero of `dist(S+t*(T-S), R)-d`, as a function of t in [0,1]. That would take <s>nine</s> seven multiplications and one division per Newton step, if I count correctly. Re-using the names from above, that would look something like this:

```
t = 0.5;
d2 = d^2;
S1T1 = S1 - T1;
S2T2 = S2 - T2;
do {
  tS1T1 = S1 - t*S1T1;
  tS2T2 = S2 - t*S2T2;
  f = tS1T1*tS1T1 + tS2T2*tS2T2 - d2;
  fp = 2*(S1T1*tS1T1 + S2T2*tS2T2);
  t = t + f/fp;
} while (f > eps);
```

Set eps to control your required accuracy, but do not set it too low – computing f does involve a subtraction that will have serious cancellation problems near the solution.

Comment: Actually an approximation would be more then sufficient as long as it's within a reasonable % of error and if it's less computationally intense.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are two solutions Q on the (TS) line (with only one solution between T and S), any solution probably involves some choice of sign, or arccos(), etc.

Therefore, a good solution is probably to put Q on the (TS) line like so (with vectors implied):

```
(1)   TQ(t) = t * TS
```

(where O is some origin).  Requiring that Q be at a distance d from R gives a 2nd degree equation in t, which is easy to solve (again, vectors are implied):

```
d^2 = |RQ(t)|^2 = |RT + TQ(t)|^2
```

The coordinates of Q can then be obtained by putting a solution t0 into equation (1), via OQ(t0) = OT + TQ(t).  The solution 0 <= t <= 1 must be chosen, so that Q lies between T and S.

Now, it may happen that the final formula has some simple interpretation in terms of trigonometric functions…  Maybe you can tell us what value of t and what coordinates you find with this method and we can look for a simpler formula?